# Running excel file in colab

Tags: pandas, excel, google-colaboratory

Getting an error message when trying to load an Excel sheet in Google `colab`. The Excel contains 5000 plus rows.

I tried: `data=pd.read_excel('/content/data_ml.xlsx')`

```
Error obtained: :---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0935045ece15> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data=pd.read_excel('/content/data_ml.xlsx')

6 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1334             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1335         if not endrec:
-> 1336             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1337         if self.debug > 1:
   1338             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: Does the Excel file have any password protection or sheet protection?

Comment: Thanks for the try. I edited the file name to data.xlsx and run the code with new path . Now the file is working without error